# WIX to Wordpress SEO

Tags: seo

I'm managing a new Wordpress, self hosted site for a client. Their old site was based on Wix, without a custom domain.

Their Wix site ranks fairly highly for certain terms in Google, we'd ideally like to keep this if at all possible - though I'm struggling to see how this would be.

- Wix doesn't support 301s away from their platform
- As the client used a wix domain name (for free) I can't simply create re-directs on the new site and map them across
- Meta Refresh header tags get stripped from the site on publish

All I can think of is a "We have moved" notice on their existing Wix site with a link to the new site - but I'm expecting an SEO hit.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to minimize any SEO impact?

Comment: Canonical tags may help solve your issue if you cant redirect the pages.

Comment: "I can't simply create re-directs on the new site" - what do you mean by this exactly? What "type" of redirects are you referring to? Do you have access to add a meta refresh, or JavaScript `window.location.replace()`?

Comment: I mean that I can't take the existing urls and re-create them on the new site so that all existing links resolve - the existing wix site is on another domain

Comment: No, there's no JavaScript Access and AFIAK no access to header meta tags - but I will check

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this strategy will work but research on net and ask questions to wix support.

1. Go for paid plan of wix which allows custom domain.
2. Register your domain with any domain seller.
3. Reach out to wix support that you want to have custom domain for your site.
4. They will surely handle the 301 redirects for mysite.wix.com to www.mysite.com
5. Move the site to wordpress in couple of months without worrying about SEO impact of domain change.

Comment: I agree with aakash, you have to buy custom domain and use Google change of address tool to get ranking back in few months, yes, it take some times to recover same kind of traffic with custom domain, then you can move to WP, where you can easily manage permalink and 301 redirect.